# Numbers: Count unique items in a column

Tags: numbers

I'd like to count the occurrence of unique items found in one column of about 120 items. I  can't find a way to do this in Numbers.app

Comment: Currently, if I do this calculation in the footer row, or another table, they both show up as "0"

Comment: Shows up as "0" because I'm not sure how to use the Count function really well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a clever solution posted in an [apple discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1495060?start=0&tstart=0).

You basically create another column, and use the formula `=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A2)=0,1,"")`. This will display a one for the first occurrence of each unique item. You then simply sum the whole column and you get your count.

Comment: This is extremely slow when there's lots of data. If that's the case, you can import your data into Google Spreadsheets and use `=COUNTUNIQUE(A:A)`

Answer (score 25):

If it doesn't have to be updated dynamically, you might also copy the cells and run something like `pbpaste | sort | uniq | wc -l`.

Comment: Copy the column and run `pbpaste| sort | uniq -c` in a terminal.

Comment: why do you need sort?

Comment: @CousinCocaine you need `sort` because `uniq` only detects repeated lines immediately following each other, not repeated lines anywhere in the input stream. See [`uniq` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uniq.1.html).

Comment: You can also use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`

Comment: This one is always better than clunky gui, thanks for the reminder bro!

Comment: This is a clean solution. It's obscene that there's no baked-in function for doing this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Numbers' (new) `Pivot Table` tool to summarize data

To get count of unique value:

1. Make sure your table is selected
2. On toolbar, click `Pivot Table`
3. In sidebar, select your column under `Fields`
4. In sidebar, under `Values`, select or change "Summarize by" to `Count (Unique)`. You may need to click the little (i) icon.

You will see the answer in the created pivot table

You can summarize by groups ("facet") by selecting additional `Fields`

You can add more results to the same table, by dragging `Fields` as new `Values`

Comment: This is the best solution, I think. Step 4 was a little tricky — what I ended up doing was dragging the green lozenge under `Rows` over to `Values` and then I could click the `(i)` and change to `Count (Unique)`.

Answer (score 0):

I just select the column and copy, go to Terminal, type `wc(return)`, paste in the copy, type Ctrl-D, and read the count.